# Showing json_encoded object not working after php 7.1 update

Tags: php, arrays

I have two websites one is running on PHP 7.0 and the other PHP 7.1, I have the ability to store a product in a shopping cart on both, this still works but a product also has options (for example a color, size etc).

This needs to be shown in the shopping cart as well or else people add the same product twice with different options but people only see the same product twice and can't differentiate between them.

I've already written that code and on PHP 7.0 it works but on 7.1 the options are empty, why could that be?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$n = 0;
$o = 0;

// Loop array inside select element where product options are selected

foreach($varpijp as $productvar) {
    // Filter anything empty

    if (!empty($productvar)) {
        $productvar['artikelid'] = $artikel['content_id'];
        $productvar['prodoptie'] = $o . $artikel['content_id'];

        // Empty options every loop

        $productopties = '';
        $productarray = '';

        // Loop options and make key useable with $key and value with $prodvalue

        foreach($productvar as $key => $prodvalue) {
            if ($key == 'Prijs') {
                $key = str_replace('Prijs', '', $key);
            } elseif ($key == 'prodoptie') {
                $key = '';
                $prodvalue = '';
            } elseif ($key == 'artikelid') {
                $key = '';
                $prodvalue = '';
            } else {
                $key = $key . ': ';
            }

            // Put results in variable $productopties

            $productopties.= $key . '' . $prodvalue . '&nbsp;&nbsp; ';
        }

        foreach($productvar as $key1 => $prodvalue1) {
            if ($key1 == 'Prijs') {
                $key1 = str_replace('Prijs', '', $key1);
            } else {
                $key1 = $key1 . ': ';
            }

            if ($key1 !== 'Prijs') {
                $productarray[] = $key1 . $prodvalue1;
                $serializedarray = json_encode($productarray);
            }
        }

        // Loop all option tags

        $productvars.= "<option value='" . $productvar['prodoptie'] . "' data-array='" . $serializedarray . "' data-optie='" . $o . "' data-src='" . $prijscalc . "'>" . $productopties . "</option>";
    }

    $n++;
    $o++;
}

echo $productvars;
```

It works fine on 7.0 like I said but when I put error reporting to show everything on my 7.1 site I get an error on this line:

```
$productarray[] = $key1 . $prodvalue1;
```

Creating an array like this apparently does not work anymore, so tried it like this:

```
$productarray = array();
$productarray[] = $key1 . $prodvalue1;
```

The error goes away but now my options are always empty and I am not sure why.

What can I do to fix this?

```
$productvars .= "<option value='".$productvar['prodoptie']."' data-array='".$serializedarray."' data-optie='".$o."' data-src='".$prijscalc."'>".$productopties."</option>";
```

In above code `$serializedarray` is what I need.

On the working site it looks for example like this:

```
["\u20ac 124,95  -  ","Aantal kratten: 1","artikelid: 40","prodoptie: 040"]
```

But on the 7.1 site a product which also has multiple options only shows me this:

```
["prodoptie: 0315"]
```

This is the error that I get:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/website/public_html/product-page.php:256

When I use the same code as 7.0

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Comment: Did you look at the PHP Error log yet, if not please do, and post the Full error message here in your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added the error at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Error appairs because your variable `$productarray` is type of string. `$productarray = '';`  you should edit this like `$productarray = [];`

Comment: You define `$productarray = '';` as a string so you can't use it as an array later. In PHP 7.1, that turned into a fatal error. In PHP 7.0 (and earlier), PHP silently casted the variable as an array.

Comment: `$productarray = '';` You defined/initialised the variable as a STRING and then attempt to use it as an array

Comment: I would also recommend that you define the variables you're using after the loop _before_ the loop. Otherwise, your code will throw a few "undefined variables" if  the loop isn't entered of if the `if`-statement in the loop doesn't evaluate as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$productarray;` is supposed to be an array, but is defined as string : `$productarray = '';`.

Replace this declaration by `$productarray = array();`

For more informations about changes from php 7.0 to 7.1, see the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php)

> String modification by character on an empty string now works like for non-empty strings, i.e. writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces, where non-integer types are converted to integer, and only the first character of the assigned string is used. **Formerly, empty strings where silently treated like an empty array.**

Comment: Thank you. The site works perfectly again now.